# URL patterns for GET

Tags: django, django-views

I want to define url pattern for the below url and read these parameters in views

```
http://example.com/user/account?id=USR1045&status=1
```

I tried

```
url(r'^user/account/(?P<id>\w+)/(?P<status>\d+)/$', useraccount),
```

In Views

```
request.GET ['id']
request.GET ['status']
```

but it is not working, please correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django url patterns [do not capture the query string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against):

> The URLconf searches against the requested URL, as a normal Python
>   string. This does not include GET or POST parameters, or the domain
>   name.
>
> For example, in a request to http://www.example.com/myapp/, the
>   URLconf will look for `myapp/`.
>
> In a request to http://www.example.com/myapp/?page=3, the URLconf will
>   look for `myapp/`.
>
> The URLconf doesn’t look at the request method. In other words, all
>   request methods – `POST`, `GET`, `HEAD`, etc. – will be routed to the same
>   function for the same URL.

So, with that in mind, your url pattern should be:

```
url(r'^user/account/$', useraccount),
```

In your `useraccount` method:

```
def useraccount(request):
    user_id = request.GET.get('id')
    status = request.GET.get('status')

    if user_id and status:
        # do stuff
    else:
        # user id or status were not in the querystring
        # do other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Querystring params and django urls pattern are not the same thing.

so, using django urls pattern:

your url:

```
http://example.com/user/account/USR1045/1
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^user/account/(?P<id>\w+)/(?P<status>\d+)/$', views.useraccount)
```

views.py

```
def useraccount(request, id, status):
```

Comment: `id()` is a built-in, best to avoid shadowing built-ins.

Comment: I agree, I used the example of syc